# Alternate between Disjunctions in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Consider the following simple program:

```
h(n0).
h(p(A,N)) :- (A=a, h(N)) ; (A=b , h(N)).
```

Query:

```
1 ?- h(p(A,N)).
A = a,
N = n0 ;
A = a,
N = p(a, n0) ;
A = a,
N = p(a, p(a, n0)) ;
A = a,
N = p(a, p(a, p(a, n0))) ;
A = a,
N = p(a, p(a, p(a, p(a, n0)))) ;
```

...

Since the first disjunct [`(A=a, h(N))`] produces infinite number of answers it cannot show the answers produced by the second disjunct [`(A=b , h(N))`].

The question is:

Is it possible to change the code so that on the query, it alternates between the solutions from the first disjunct and the second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a fair listing of the results of h/1 you can use an auxiliary predicate, say h2/2 that consists of two goals: 1) A predicate pairs/1 that is only describing the the structure of your solution without concrete values:

```
pairs(n0).
pairs(p(A,N)) :-
   pairs(N).
```

And yields the following answers:

```
   ?- pairs(X).
X = n0 ? ;
X = p(_A,n0) ? ;
X = p(_A,p(_B,n0)) ? ;
X = p(_A,p(_B,p(_C,n0))) ? 
...
```

2) Your predicate h/1 as the second goal that describes what the variables `_A, _B, _C,...` actually are:

```
h2(X) :-
   pairs(X),
   h(X).
```

If you query this predicate you get the desired results:

```
   ?- h2(X).
X = n0 ? ;
X = p(a,n0) ? ;
X = p(b,n0) ? ;
X = p(a,p(a,n0)) ? ;
X = p(a,p(b,n0)) ? ;
X = p(b,p(a,n0)) ? ;
X = p(b,p(b,n0)) ? ;
X = p(a,p(a,p(a,n0))) ? ;
...
```

Note, how the first goal pairs/2 is producing your nested pair-structure one pair at a time. Then the second goal, your original predicate, is producing all possible combinations of `a`'s and `b`'s for that very pair. Then h/2 is backtracking to the next pair produced by pairs/2. And so on.